# Run html file through XAMPP vsCode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, xampp

I'm building a website and am trying to run it through a web server using XAMPP and the 'open in browser extension'. When I run the page I get an error saying:

Error: Invalid Configuration! Document root folder must be set to use http://localhost. Falling back to scheme file:///

I have already configured the 'open in browser' extension to run the file through a customer browser path like this: http://localhost/xampp/htdocs/Welcome.html (Welcome.html is my index file and is located in the htdocs folder of XAMPP)

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: As it is a static page, have you considered to use [Live Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for the root folder of your webserver and if I remember this right in should be:

```
http://localhost/Welcome.html
```

The htdocs folder is = the localhost on the server. So anything placed in that folder is on the web. AT least on your local network.